# WiX - RegistryKey with new generated GUID each install

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I have a WiX setup for my application. Now I want to write a write a freshly created new GUID to the registry for each install.

Pseudo:

```
<RegistryValue Value='[NEWGUID]' Root="HKMU" Key='SOFTWARE\!(wix.Manufacturer)\!(wix.ProductName)' Name='InstallGuid' Type='string'/>
```

Is there a way to make WiX/MSI generate a GUID in place of **[NEWGUID]** for *each install* without using a custom action?

All i can find is this thread which suggest I have to use custom action:

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Create-New-Guid-in-Installer-td708469.html

but it's from 2008 so I wondering if anything has changed/become easier?

Answer (score 0):

In Wix to generate s random guid use `*` . For example

```
     <Component Id="RegistryComponent" Guid="*" Directory="PATHNAME">
```

Comment: That only works for some attributes on some elements. And that would only generate the GUID at build, not for each install. Or am I missing someting?

Comment: If you want to install multiple instances of same installer you need to use TRANSCRIPS and MSINEWINSTANCE when u run the msi

Comment: ofc you can always bind bew guid with custom action :